# Why does XmlRootElementJaxbProvider in Jersey use SAXSource

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jersey-2.0

Reading through the Jersey source, I noticed that [one of the default `MessageBodyReader` implementations](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/media/jaxb/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jaxb/internal/XmlRootElementJaxbProvider.java) creates a `SAXSource` which it then passes to the `Unmarshaller`.

```
@Override
protected Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, MediaType mediaType,
        Unmarshaller u, InputStream entityStream)
        throws JAXBException {
    final SAXSource s = getSAXSource(spf.provide(), entityStream);
    if (type.isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class)) {
        return u.unmarshal(s);
    } else {
        return u.unmarshal(s, type).getValue();
    }
}
```

My question: why is the `InputStream` wrapped in a `SAXSource`?

`Unmarshaller.unmarshal` can accept an `InputStream` on its own, and `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl` seems to use the same internal method for unmarshalling whether a `SAXSource` or `InputStream` is supplied. The only difference seems to be that `XmlRootElementJaxbProvider` uses dependency injection to provide a `Factory<SAXParserFactory>` which is used to get a `SAXParserFactory`, whereas in the bowels of `UnmarshallerImpl` the method `SAXParserFactory.newInstance()` is called directly. Is the desire to be able to inject a custom `SAXParserFactory` the only reason `unmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXSource)` is used instead of `unmarshaller.unmarshal(InputStream)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git blame is your friend.  The original implementation (back in 2009) used StreamSource.  The reason for the change was a bug, https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-323.

At the time, yes, SAXParserFactory.newInstance() is called directly but the code then sets various features on the parser (presumably these features were not set by JAXB at the time).  You can see this here: https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/2057807f211958860a7557abf49ac4cd6a5ef1fb/jersey-core/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/core/impl/provider/xml/SAXParserContextProvider.java

I'm not sure if that change is still necessary but that was the original motivation for the change.  It appears that code has then passed relatively unmodified ever since.

The full diff of the change is [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/commit/2057807f211958860a7557abf49ac4cd6a5ef1fb) although it is not super obvious.  The readFrom method was added to XmlRootElementProvider to override the method that used StreamSource in AbstractRootElementProvider.

Comment: Thanks, I should have dug a bit deeper into where the `SAXParserFactory` was coming from. It just seems like a roundabout way to set the `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` property. I would have expected to find that property set in the `getSAXSource` method. I guess the factory ensures that all `SAXParserFactory` instances have secure processing instead of needing to set secure processing each time `newInstance` is used.